# Tkinter app - Allowing for multiple languages

Tags: python, internationalization, tkinter

I'm writing my first Tk app with Python. I can't find an example of how to create a UI which supports multiple languages for the on screen text/dialogs. Initially I'd support English, but would like the ability to add others (from a file, perhaps XML) and have users select which language they want from an applications preferences menu.

Does anyone have advice towards the best approach?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The GUI should construct its text with strings from a default language. So, for example, your code would look something like this:

```
import Tkinter as Tk
root = Tk.Tk()
root.title('Program')
menuButton = Tk.Button(root, text='Menu')
menuButton.grid(row=0, column=0)
root.mainloop()
```

Changing the language is as simple as modifying each Tk widget depending on the selected language. For example,

```
def change_language(lang):
    if lang == 'English':
        root.title('Program')
        menuButton.config(text='Menu')
    elif lang == 'Spanish':
        root.title('Programa')
        menuButton.config(text='Menú')
```

To make it easier to write the code, you could store your language data in a file (e.g. csv), parse it into lists or dictionaries, and have something like this:

```
english = ['Program', 'Menu']
spanish = ['Programa', 'Menú']

def change_language_2(lang):
    root.title(lang[0])
    menuButton.config(text=lang[1])
```

Comment: Great, one follow up, how would I refresh a running Tk UI?

Comment: Sorry, I was totally mistaken. You could make the UI construction a function and destroy/redraw the entire thing after `change_language`, but see my edit for the better version - modifying each Tk instance directly.

Comment: Kind of doing msg catalogues by hand.

Answer (score 8):

There are a multiple parts to this.

The Tk framework uses the Tcl [msgcat](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/msgcat.htm) package for its internal messages, so you might have to use parts of that for the system provided locale things. The available messages are stored inside the `$::tk_library/msgs` folder, which is usually located inside your Tcl/Tk installation.

Python usually uses the GNU gettext system for localization, see the descriptions of the [gettext](http://docs.python.org/2/library/gettext.html) python module for an introduction.

So to make your UI localized, you would run all your user visible texts through `gettext.gettext()` or its alias `_()` before using it in labels or texts. Once done you can than provide message catalogues in the PO/POT/MO format (see [polib](http://polib.readthedocs.org/en/latest/quickstart.html) for some nice python lib to handle those) for your translated texts.

You could also use the Tcl msgcat system instead, if you provide a small Python wrapper around the Tcl `msgcat::mc` commands. Or any other msg catalogue system you like, [pybabel](http://babel.edgewall.org/wiki/Documentation) might also be worth a look.

Comment: Wow, this is really interesting, it'll take me a while to get my head around all this

Comment: Hmm, if I were planning to distribute this app, would I be able to use this method to generate a multilingual app without having to package the gettext module and a bunch of dependancies?

Answer (score 1):

I recommend using Babel for python it's an amazing package for text extraction, internationalization, and localization. What I do usually in my projects I put all of the hardcoded strings in 1 file/folder i.e. string.py and using babel I extract all of the hardcoded strings in that file into PO files for the target language and from there I translate the files and compile them using Babel.

Please have a look at the following tutorial for using Babel with Python:
[Babel Tutorial With Python](https://phrase.com/blog/posts/i18n-advantages-babel-python/)

For people who are wondering how to use the compiled files in Babel here's a snippet of code.

```
from babel.support import Translations
LOCALE_PATH = 'locale' # the path of the locale folder
LANGUAGE = 'en_US' # what language you wanna use
translations = Translations.load(LOCALE_PATH, [LANGUAGE])
_ = translations.gettext

print(_('Hi')) # it would be translated to the target value from the PO file
```

I hope it will be helpful