# Is It Possible To Upgrade The Tkinter Library In Python?

Tags: python, tkinter, python-idle

I really want to know is it possible to upgrade the tkinter library in python because currently i am working on a project named Translator where text of any language will be converted to a text of any other language and vice versa same as our google translator. So the problem I am facing is that whenever I want to write a text in any other language it is not taking, it is showing ????. This means that the tkinter textbox is not supporting any other language other than English. I have seen people saying that if you upgrade the tkinter library to the next version it will work. So can someone please help me out with this!!

[image] I have provided a screenshot here to check what is happening with me right now.

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21045178/10292330) help?

Answer (score 1):

Each version of Python comes with corresponding versions of the Python-coded tkinter and C-coded _tkinter modules.  (Tkinter imports _tkinter.)  One cannot upgrade tkinter except by upgrading Python.

That said, the tkinter that comes with current versions of Python (3.10+) potentially display all unicode characters.  What are you using? The following is from IDLE's settings dialog font sample on Windows with SourceCodePro font.

```
<ASCII/Latin1>
AaBbCcDdEeFfGgHhIiJj
1234567890#:+=(){}[]
¢£¥§©«®¶½ĞÀÁÂÃÄÅÇÐØß

<IPA,Greek,Cyrillic>
ɐɕɘɞɟɤɫɮɰɷɻʁʃʆʎʞʢʫʭʯ
ΑαΒβΓγΔδΕεΖζΗηΘθΙιΚκ
БбДдЖжПпФфЧчЪъЭэѠѤѬӜ

<Hebrew, Arabic>
אבגדהוזחטיךכלםמןנסעף
ابجدهوزحطي٠١٢٣٤٥٦٧٨٩

<Devanagari, Tamil>
०१२३४५६७८९अआइईउऊएऐओऔ
௦௧௨௩௪௫௬௭௮௯அஇஉஎ

<East Asian>
〇一二三四五六七八九
汉字漢字人木火土金水
가냐더려모뵤수유즈치
あいうえおアイウエオ
```

If characters do not display, the issue is with the OS and font.  Characters not in the Basic Multilingual Plane do, however, interfere with editing.  Everything you see above *is* in the BMP and the same will be true of most anything that people want to insert into a text translator.

Post the minimum amount of code needed to illustrate your problem: just one text-display widget and code to insert text that results in '?'s.